# fill listView frequently in a layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating a layout that shows Database values.But this error appears in logcat:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

this is my ListActivity:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Row_User extends ListActivity
    {


        private static String   TAG     = "Row_User";
        static final String[]   FROM    = { Data.C_USER, Data.C_PASS };
        static final int[]      TO      = { R.id.row_user, R.id.row_pass };
        Cursor                  cursor;
        SimpleCursorAdapter     adapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {

                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-------Start");

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.row_users);


                make_and_fill_rows();

                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate-------End");

            }



        static final ViewBinder VIEW_BINDER = new ViewBinder()
                                                {


                                                    public
                                                            boolean
                                                            setViewValue(
                                                                    View view,
                                                                    Cursor cursor,
                                                                    int columnIndex)
                                                        {

                                                            Log.d(
                                                                    TAG,
                                                                    "Entering switch-case...");
                                                            switch (view
                                                                    .getId())
                                                                {
                                                                    case R.id.row_user:
                                                                        ((TextView) view)
                                                                                .setText("userrrrrr");
                                                                        return true;

                                                                    case R.id.row_pass:
                                                                        ((TextView) view)
                                                                                .setText("passssssss");
                                                                        return true;


                                                                    default:
                                                                        return false;
                                                                }
                                                        }

                                                };

        private void make_and_fill_rows()
            {

                Log.d(TAG, "make_and_fill_rows-----Start");

                cursor = ((Constant) getApplication()).data.query("1=1", null);

                adapter =
                            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                    this,
                                    R.layout.row_users,
                                    cursor,
                                    FROM,
                                    TO);
                adapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);

                setTitle("کاربران");
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                Log.d(TAG, "make_and_fill_rows-----End");
            }

    }
```

this is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="user" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="pass" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a button in another layout, that Starts this activity in onClickListener.
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you try doing as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
    android:id="@+id/list"
```

with this

```
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

The Exception you are getting

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Its saying you must have to define your `ListView` with already existed resource id `android.R.id.list` which you can get using `@android:id/list`